# No conversion from java code in the jsp file to the web resource on the server , as shown in the address bar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp

I'm doing a java web project using maven on Eclipse and Spring. I have a jsp file with this code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1  class="text-center text-white" >Welcome, choose your way!</h1>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stock" class="btn mr-3">Stock</a>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/shoppingCartController/shoppingCartPage" class="btn">Shopping Cart</a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

When I run the program and the web page appears, I click on one of the  hyperlink tags. But I get the error message `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found`.
This url appears in the address bar

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-jdbc/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/stock
```

and you notice that no conversion of this code (`${pageContext.request.contextPath}`) is performed in the corresponding resource, that it should be

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-unikey/stock
```

This seems strange to me because I had already created the same program on Eclipse as a dynamic web project and not as a maven project, and everything worked. Even my programming teacher can't understand why. Any suggestions please?